# This Program Can not Be Run in DOS Mode

Tags: privilege-escalation

I'm doing a pentest on a Windows XP box and have achieved a shell with low privileges. As such, I am trying to escalate my privileges. However, every .exe I try to run is giving me "This program can not be run in DOS mode". Is there any sort of configuration I need to change on the box or is there a different strategy for privilege escalation in an environment such as this?"

Comment: Any chance the assemblies are .net? That would explain the error.

Comment: How did you transfer the file to the machine you're attempting to execute on?

Comment: @AstroDan I'm not sure what you mean. I have tried compiling my own .exes with i686-w64-mingw32-gcc compiler for linux as well as using other windows compiled .exes such as netcat to try for the higher privileged shell.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES there is an anonymous FTP server with read/write

Comment: Try opening the program in notepad and look for the following: This program cannot be run in DOS mode. If the exe header has this then the program cannot be run in DOS mode.

Comment: @EnigmaticCipher Are you transferring the file with Binary mode enabled?

Comment: @DKNUCKLES That was part of the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Background

That message is from the basic header that every Windows (PE format) executable has. The message (and the code that displays it) is technically editable, but all compilers seem to just emit code that displays that same string and then exits. It's 16-bit executable code (like a DOS `.COM` file), intended to be displayed when you try to run the program on MS-DOS or similar pre-Windows systems. Windows' program loader typically skips over it.

#### Explanation

However, there is one case where Windows might display that message: when you try to run a PE that is compiled for a more advanced version of Windows than the one you're using, especially if the main program code is for a different CPU architecture than the OS can support. (This is similar to, for example, trying to run Win32 code on 16-bit DOS.) From a GUI, you'd get a pop-up error, but in the command line, you may well just get that message.

The obvious candidate here is that you're trying to run code on the (hideously obsolete) Windows XP, and you say you're using "i686-**w64**-mingw32-gcc". If you're compiling 64-bit binaries for Windows XP, it's extremely likely they won't work; while a 64-bit build of XP technically exists (it's actually a different kernel version, 5.2 vs. 5.1, but it's branded as XP), it was never widely used; the extremely vast majority of XP boxes are 32-bit only. If you want a quick check for 32-bit vs. 64-bit from the command line, check for the presence of a `\Windows\SysWOW64` directory (which holds 32-bit system binaries on 64-bit machines); if it doesn't exist, you're running on a 32-bit OS.

#### Recommendation

- Unless you A) need 64-bit for something, and B) know your target is 64-bit, only use 32-bit payloads.
- Make sure your code and compiler are targeting XP (Vista and later added a ton of new APIs that will prevent a program which uses them from running on XP).
- Consider spinning up an XP VM to test whether your payloads run locally before trying them on the target machine.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you have delivered the payload correctly, I had a similar issue when transferring accesschk.exe via ftp. FTP allows transfer in ascii and binary modes, if you transfer it in binary mode it should work.

Binary mode transfers the files, bit by bit, as they are on the FTP server. Ascii mode, however, will download the text directly. You can type ascii or binary to switch between the types.

To do this, connect to the ftp service and type "binary", you should get a response saying "200 Type set to I"

put the file again and run the executable.

Comment: FYI, this was covered in the comments to the question

Comment: It works in 2019

Comment: boy finally found it after 5 hours...